# Best practices for defining an entirely new type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, global-variables

I have an execution environment with several constants globally:

```
TOP = 1
TOP_RIGHT = 2
RIGHT = 3
BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4
BOTTOM = 5
BOTTOM_LEFT = 6
LEFT = 7
TOP_LEFT = 8
```

---

It is clear to me that these 8 constants are not just arbitrary constants, but actually a set of directions.  Therefore, I would like to have them be of the `DIRECTION` type, so that I can do things like this:

```
let test: DIRECTION = TOP_LEFT;
let foo: DIRECTION = TOP;
let bar: DIRECTION = LEFT;
let target: DIRECTION = RIGHT;
```

---

I've considered several options for how to make this happen (i.e. what to put in the `direction.d.ts` file):

1. `enum`s require a ton of syntax & boilerplate to just get off the ground, so they are undesirable in this case.
2. When I use the `type` keyword, it seems unable to create a new type that is not simply an alias of another. (e.g. `type DIRECTION=integer;` is allowed, but `type DIRECTION;` is not.  Defining DIRECTION as an alias of integer is undesirable because, despite the fact that they are technically integers in the environment, `BOTTOM-2` is nonsensical, and should cause an error.
3. `interface DIRECTION {}` seems to result in the desired behavior, letting me define this new type.  However, it seems like quite an abuse of the typing system (I am under the impression that TS's interfaces were basically the equivalent of classes.)

---

What's the most TS-friendly way to accomplish this?

Comment: Aww, what was wrong with the old question? I even upvoted it :}

Comment: @user2864740 I felt it would be wrong to change an already-answered question so significantly.  (Just not fair to the guy who answered it), especially since, while it was a perfectly valid question, I wasn't really asking what I meant to ask.

Comment: Ahh, I didn't see it had been answered.

Comment: @user2864740 It got answered twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reference to idea #3, as posted above:

```
interface DIRECTION {}

declare const TOP: DIRECTION;
declare const TOP_RIGHT: DIRECTION;
declare const RIGHT: DIRECTION;
declare const BOTTOM_RIGHT: DIRECTION;
declare const BOTTOM: DIRECTION;
declare const BOTTOM_LEFT: DIRECTION;
declare const LEFT: DIRECTION;
declare const TOP_LEFT: DIRECTION;
```

This code is significantly more concise than the solution with `enum`.

I am still looking for ways to improve it, however, so suggestions/changes are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `const` and `type` for this:

```
const TOP = 1
const TOP_RIGHT = 2
type DIRECTION = 1 | 2

let x: DIRECTION = TOP
```

However, I believe `enum` is a better solution for this purpose.

For example, this is valid but not desirable:

```
const ONE = 1
let x: DIRECTION = ONE
```

Answer (score 0):

In reference to solution #1, as originally posted:

```
declare const enum Direction {
    TOP = 1,
    TOP_RIGHT = 2,
    RIGHT = 3,
    BOTTOM_RIGHT = 4,
    BOTTOM = 5,
    BOTTOM_LEFT = 6,
    LEFT = 7,
    TOP_LEFT = 8
}
declare const TOP=Direction.TOP
declare const TOP_RIGHT=Direction.TOP_RIGHT
declare const RIGHT=Direction.RIGHT
declare const BOTTOM_RIGHT=Direction.BOTTOM_RIGHT
declare const BOTTOM=Direction.BOTTOM
declare const BOTTOM_LEFT=Direction.BOTTOM_LEFT
declare const LEFT=Direction.LEFT
declare const TOP_LEFT=Direction.TOP_LEFT
```